# postgresql recovery after reboot

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postegresql and added a database which I was using as part of a local server. However, I restarted the computer and my Postgresql database seems to be gone. The [Postegresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/server-start.html) says that the data should be placed in /usr/local/pgsql/data however I did not do this and this directory is empty on my system. Also, I  cannot find a postgresql config file so I am not sure where Postgreql may have been putting my databases.

Has this happened to anyone before? If so, is there a way to recover my databases? Fortunately these databases are not so old that there is irrevocable memory loss but i would prefer to recover my data if possible.

If I can't find my data I will need to restart /recreate my data although I would prefer not to.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
zach cp

Comment: If you didn't use /usr/local/pgsql/data for your data, where did you store it? Unless you used a RAM drive, it's still there. You can store the data anywhere, no problem at all.

Comment: Which operating system and which version? How did you install Postgres (a package or from source, which version)? Is this a first restart after installing Postgres? Did you try to upgrade? Did all partitions mount successfully? Your description is so vague it is impossible to help you - maybe you should get some professional support.

Comment: @FrankHeikens i didn't explicitly specify where to put the data. I installed postgresql via yum on centoS, added a postgres user and a database and everything was cool until the restart. looks like my data is in /var/lib/pgsql/data  so i should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate your data try the following command:

```
sudo find / -name postgresql.conf
```

The problem probably is that your server isn't automatically started. You can manually start it with a command like:

```
pg_ctl start -D <your data dir>
```

If you need help starting it automatically please specify which os/distribution you are running and how you installed postgresql (source/yum/rpm/...)

Comment: than you Eelke. Looks like postgres installed in /var/lib/pgsql/data/ I installed Postgresql from YUM on CentOS 5.4 (EPEL package repo) and would appreciate suggestions on hoe to automatically start postgres.

Comment: hm. try: "chkconfig postgresql on"